# Filter Conversion From Low Pass

Tags: java, algorithm, signal-processing

I have a basic low-pass sensor filter like this:

```
if (logic) {
      return (prev + ALPHA * (input - prev));

}
```

How can I convert the same to a high-pass filter?

**Background:**  I am trying to do this om Android platform. Filter the given input against the previous values and return a low-pass filtered result. I read umpteen resources and yet I am confused on how to implement one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your `prev` is the previous output. For high pass filter you will need to keep also the previous input.
Then, you can get this by:

```
if (logic){
    return ALPHA*(prev_out + input - prev_in);
}
```

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter#Algorithmic_implementation) for more information.

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot! Your implementation helps me understand the Wiki example.